# Замена текста в ячейке таблицы на input (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Есть текст в ячейке таблицы: `<td>ckick me</td>`. Нужно, чтобы по клику вместо  этого текста появлялся input:`<input  name="my_name" type="text" required="">`
На странице таких мест может быть несколько.  Соответственно каждому инпуту можно было присвоить уникальное значение(вручную)
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nameCounter = 0;
  $(document).on("click", "td", function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
      var newName = "my_name_" + (++nameCounter);
      $(this).html("<input name='" + newName + "' type='text' required='' value='" + $(this).text() + "' />");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td></td><td>kick me</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>kick me</td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а как можно задать разным ячейкам разные нэймы вставляемых инпутов?

Comment: Для применения скрипта к конкретному классу,  заменяем
"td"  на ".my_class".

Comment: @DaVinchi - не возражаю